# Missing stems in stem-and-leaf plot

Tags: data-visualization

[image: Stem-leaf plot]

Why is there no 17| xxx in the stem leaf plot?

Thanks.

Comment: values in $[1.7,1.8)$ are in the second half of the values to the right of the `16` stem. You should review how stem and leaf plots are defined.

Comment: What do you mean second half? I actually don't know the definition of stem and leaf plots. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The leaf digits are in order. So when the order reverses at the third digit: `16|07035..` (moving from 7 down to 0 rather than up), it clearly signifies the stem must increase by 1. So (just from looking at the plot) the first five numbers are `1.60 1.67 1.70 1.73 1.75` ... and if you look up at the original data, that's correct (to three figures). It's actually possible for it to be ambiguous  (e.g. on the above scale, you couldn't tell `1.60 1.60 1.70 1.71` from `1.60 1.70 1.70 1.71`) without marking the change in some fashion.

Comment: On the next stem (18), the second half begins when the leaf `2` comes after the `8` leaf, signifying `1.88 1.92`.

Answer (score 2):

You can see that all the values in the stem are multiples of $2$, corresponding to values which are multiples of $0.2$, a number chosen automatically by the software.

You can double the length of the stem by using a parameter

```
stem(eruptions, scale=2)
```

and with this data, this will probably introduce a row

```
17 | 0355555588
```